# ViewPager/Fragment overlapping LinearLayout at bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, overlapping

I have a ViewPager which shows `Fragments` and I want that on the top, and a simple `LinearLayout` on the bottom. But, the `Fragments` are overlapping the layout at the bottom. I want the `Fragment` to end right about the `LinearLayout`. See picture:

[image]

**XML with ViewPager**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/steps_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/finish_checklist_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white_glossy"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="@string/finish_checklist" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**XML of Fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
android:background="#fff" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:text="@string/step_order_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/step_order"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="26sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/step_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/result_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- YES/NO BUTTONS -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_no"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_white_glossy"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/button_no" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_yes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/button_no"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_white_glossy"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/button_yes" />
<!-- END YES/NO BUTTONS -->
```

Comment: do u need the fragment to be there above the linear layout ?

Answer (score 1):

I used android:layout_below element here.

layout_below your ViewPager id.

and this layout as vertical

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

In `all your xml files`, should define the background color for it, it will solve the problem :

Add this `android:background="@android:color/black"` in to the View tag you defined.

*p/s : This case only avoid Background was overlapped.*